# Laravel-Como puedo insertar en tablas con relacion de muchos a muchos cuando tengo llaves foraneas creadas en mysql mediante migraciones?

Tags: mysql, laravel-5, controller, insert, relaciones

Cuando someto la forma, me muestra esto: error:Integrity constraint violation: 1452 Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (bolsa_empleo.aplicante_empleo, CONSTRAINT aplicantes_empleo_aplicante_usuario_id_foreign FOREIGN KEY (aplicante_usuario_id) REFERENCES aplicantes (id) ON DELETE CASCADE) (SQL: insert into aplicante_empleo (aplicante_usuario_id, created_at, empleo_id, updated_at) values (4, 2018-10-01 23:46:56, 2, 2018-10-01 23:46:56))

¿Cómo puedo hacer una inserción en dos tablas relacionadas? En este caso, sería de muchos a muchos su relacion.No sé si crear las relaciones en mysql de antemano podría estar causando el problema... si necesitan más información, hágamelo saber, por favor. Estoy utilizando laravel 5.6 He probado con attach() pero sin resultados y me muestra el mismo mensaje.

Este es el código que se está ejecutando para la tarea. Primero guarda los datos en la tabla de aplicantes y luego debería hacer una inserción en aplicante_empleo, que es la tabla intermedia, pero esta parte no esta funcionando y me muestra el error antes mencionado.

```
    public function store(Request $request, $id) {
    $this->validate($request, [
          'carta_solicitud' => 'required'
      ]);
    $aplicante = new Aplicante;
    $aplicante->carta_solicitud = $request->input('carta_solicitud');
    $aplicante->empleos_id = $request->input('empleo');
    $aplicante->estado = 'pendiente';
    $aplicante->usuario_id = auth()->user()->id;

    $aplicante->save();
    $aplicante->empleos()->sync([$id],false);

    return redirect("panelusuario");
  }
```

Estos son los modelos para las relaciones entre las tablas

```
<?php

namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Aplicante extends Model
{
     protected $primaryKey = 'usuario_id';

     public $incrementing = false;



      function empleos() {
          return $this->belongsToMany('App\Models\Empleo')->withTimeStamps();
      }

      function user() {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Models\User','usuario_id');
     }

     function perfil() {
        return $this->hasOne('App\Models\Perfil', 'perfil');
     }
}

<?php

namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Empleo extends Model
{


  function categoria() {
   return $this->belongsTo('App\Models\EmpleoCategoria');
}
function user() {
   return $this->belongsTo('App\Models\User','usuario_id');
}

function aplicantes() {
     return $this->belongsToMany('App\Models\Aplicante', 'aplicante_empleo', 'empleo_id', 'aplicante_usuario_id')->withTimeStamps();
 }
}
```

Estas son las migraciones con sus respectivas llaves foraneas creadas.

```
Schema::create('aplicantes', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->text('carta_solicitud');
            $table->string('estado');
            $table->timestamps();
            $table->integer('usuario_id')->unsigned();
            $table->integer('empleo_id')->unsigned();
            $table->foreign('empleo_id')->references('id')
            ->on('empleos')
            ->onDelete('cascade');
            $table->foreign('usuario_id')->references('id')
                ->on('users')
                ->onDelete('cascade');

        });
  Schema::create('aplicante_empleo', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->integer('aplicante_usuario_id')->unsigned();
            $table->integer('empleo_id')->unsigned();
            $table->timestamps();
            $table->foreign('aplicante_usuario_id')->references('id')
                ->on('aplicantes')
                ->onDelete('cascade');
            $table->foreign('empleo_id')->references('id')
            ->on('empleos')
            ->onDelete('cascade');
        });
Schema::create('empleos', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->string('titulo');
            $table->text('cuerpo');
            $table->decimal('salario');
            $table->integer('categoria_id')->unsigned();
            $table->string('posicion_tipo');
            $table->string('duracion_proyecto');
            $table->integer('usuario_id')->unsigned();
            $table->timestamps();
            $table->foreign('usuario_id')->references('id')
                ->on('users')
                ->onDelete('cascade');
                $table->foreign('categoria_id')->references('id')
                    ->on('empleo_categoria')
                    ->onDelete('cascade');

        });
```

Cada una de las tablas forma parte para la creación de una bolsa de empleo pequeña.